# How to get or share some data from a client in a lobby to others over a network before they join the room in PUN2?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

I am new to PUN2. I am facing an issue that I want to describe some betting amount for joining my room which I define at the time of room creation. The issue is that I want that amount must be shown to others when they are in a lobby, from where they could decide whether they join/not by paying that amount. For this I am doing:
I have 1 MenuManager.cs script in which

```
public InputField amount;
[SerializeField] Transform _content; //container of list
[SerializeField] RoomListing _roomListing;
List<RoomListing> _listings = new List<RoomListing>();

public int SetBetAmount()
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(amount.text))
    {

        return -1;
    }
    else
        return (int.Parse(amount.text));

}
```

// The Script that runs when Create Room Button Clicks as follow:

```
public void OnCreateRoomBtnClicked()
    {
        string roomName = "Room " + Random.Range(1, 800);
        int maxPlayersInt = SetMaxPlayers();
        RoomOptions roomOptions = new RoomOptions();
        roomOptions.MaxPlayers = (byte)maxPlayersInt;
        string[] roomPropertiesInLobbby = { "betAmount" };
        betAmount = SetBetAmount();
        //customRoomProps["betAmount"] = (byte)SetBetAmount();
        Debug.Log("Bet Amount Updated" + customRoomProps["betAmount"]);
        SetLaps();
        roomOptions.CustomRoomPropertiesForLobby = roomPropertiesInLobbby;
        roomOptions.CustomRoomProperties = customRoomProps;
        PhotonNetwork.CreateRoom(roomName, roomOptions);
    }
```

OnRoomListUpdate Callback works fine for info data but not sending correct betAmount but the garbage value 0;

```
 public override void OnRoomListUpdate(List<RoomInfo> roomList)
    {
        foreach (RoomInfo info in roomList)
        {
            if (info.RemovedFromList)
            {
                int index = _listings.FindIndex(x => x.RoomInfo.Name == info.Name);
                if (index != -1)
                {
                    Destroy(_listings[index].gameObject);
                    _listings.RemoveAt(index);
                }
            }

        else
        {
            RoomListing listing = Instantiate(_roomListing, _content);
            if (listing != null)
            {
                listing.GetComponent<RoomListing>().bettingAmt = -3; //there I tried betAmount but it sends 0
                listing.SetRoomInfo(info);
                _listings.Add(listing);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have also tried this but not sure how to do this

```
 public override void OnJoinedLobby()
    {
        //if (customRoomProps.ContainsKey("betAmount"))
        //{
        //    //Debug.Log("Call From Master");
        //    object _amount;
        //    if (customRoomProps.TryGetValue("betAmount", out _amount))
        //    {

        //        Debug.Log("Bet Amount" + _amount.ToString());
        //        betAmountS = (int)_amount;
        //        Debug.Log("BetAmount  " + betAmount);
        //    }
        //}

        //else
        //{
        //    Debug.Log("Call From local");
        //}
    }
```

Plus, I have also tried PUNRPC but it works when others join the Room then they could see that data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have your entire code so I can only suspect what happens but my guess is the following:

The key is definitely added to the room properties otherwise it wouldn't return `0` but throw a `KeyNotFoundException`.

So from your given code I guess you somewhere have a predefined

```
private Hashtable customRoomProps = new Hashtable ();
private int betAmount;
```

and somewhere already set

```
customRoomProps ["betAmount"] = betAmount;
```

now when doing

```
betAmount = SetBetAmount();
```

you expect that the value is also updated within the `customRoomProps`.

**BUT** `int` is a **value-type**! The value you stored in the `customRoomProps` is a **copy by value** of whatever value was currently stored in `betAmount` the moment you added it.

The value stored in `customRoomProps` is in no way related to the `betAmount` anymore!

You rather need to set the value the moment you need it

```
betAmount = SetBetAmount();
customRoomProps["betAmount"] = betAmount;
```

basically the line you have commented out.

---

And then in `OnRoomListUpdate` you should be able to get it like

```
if(info.CustomProperties.TryGetValue("betAmount", out var betAmount))
{
    listing.GetComponent<RoomListing>().bettingAmt = (int) betAmount;
}
```